# Comment within an xml element?

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to comment within an xml element ? like below

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"  <!-- added by me to disable shadow on android 5.0 -->
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

if not, is there any otherway to comment there ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. Comments are not allowed in an XML open tag.